# Xamarin: RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks - Error on Prelaunche: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

if have code implemented. On VS Debug Run, no error. Also App works but in Pre-Launch from Google-Play Sorte, got this error-message:

> "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void
> crc6438c23e30aebeb336.MainApplication.n_onCreate() (tried
> Java_crc6438c23e30aebeb336_MainApplication_n_1onCreate and
> Java_crc6438c23e30aebeb336_MainApplication_n_1onCreate__)"

Code:

```
...
 [Application]
    public partial class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    {
        public static bool IsApplicationInForeground { get; private set; }

        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
          :base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            try { RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this); } catch { }
            
            //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
        }

        public override void OnTerminate()
        {
            base.OnTerminate();
            try { UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this); } catch { }
        }

        public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) //?
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) //?
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity) //?
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
            IsApplicationInForeground = true;
        }

        public override void OnTrimMemory(TrimMemory level)
        {
            IsApplicationInForeground &= level != TrimMemory.UiHidden;

            base.OnTrimMemory(level);
        }

        public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) //?
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity) //?
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity) //?
        {
        }
    }

...
```

Comment: what build options have you chosen for linking

Comment: Try run your app from VS using the Release configuration, you should see the same error. In such case check which linker options you have chosen as @TheGeneral mentions. If you have set them to "Link All", that might be your issue. Since no code directly references MainApplication and its OnCreate method, this code may be stripped out by the linker.